# How to disable GitHub code-review on pull-requests?

Tags: github

I want to apply a different git workflow in my organization than what is usually used with Github.

In my flow we have an external code-review tool which I wish to use instead of github's code-review tool which is not as satisfying. Is there a way to prevent people from using github's code review tools?

Comment: Too bad this doesn't get any attention, we have this need as well. Using two different code-review systems at once creates so much confusion, and GitHub's review simply has too many shortcomings.